# Image Intrinsic Size Is Different Comparing With Local And Production

Tags: product-images

i have two product pages whose images are different in sizes when they are rendered , even though i have used the media backup from production in local and and all code base are same without any changes , and i have also ran the command - bin/magento catalog:image:resize , still no difference , the size in production is 500 x 300 for all images in PDP in gallery (intrinsic size) , whereas in local it is 2000 x 2000 for all (same as in prod), the only difference is in local i'm in developer mode , will that affect anything ? And yes i even tried switching to production and even stores->configruation are same as prod.

Comment: The issue is resolved now , actually we are using fastly CDN in our local env , since it is a cloud project they have provision for image optimization, after disabling it , the images were rendering from the cache directory , one thing i learned from this is , when using the fastly CDN we have to give the image sizes usually in view.xml file in the themes or modules , then re-generate the images and then flush the cache in fastly and varnish etc to view the results.

Answer (score 0):

If the code base is same in both the environment then do the following changes in your local instance.

Delete the **generated** folder in your local directory.

Then run the below commands

```
php bin/magento s:up;
php bin/magento s:d:c;
php bin/magento s:s:d -f;
php bin/magento c:f;
```